# tcpdf library. doesnt print when the contents of the db is too many

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

im trying to write a code where i have to print the contents of my database and output it as a pdf file

however i seem to have encountered a problem

when i export everything in my database my pdf does not show anything

but if i limit it for example LIMIT 5

it works and prints the data properly

is there a way to make it print my database without having to use limit since i need it printed in a single pdf file

//settings for the tcpdf library

```
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    include('connect.php');
    include('../libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
    include('../libraries/tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');

    // create new PDF document
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Test');
    $pdf->SetTitle('Report');
    $pdf->SetSubject('Report');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('Test, Report, Data, Form, Results');



    // set default header data
    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
    $pdf->setFooterData($tc=array(0,64,0), $lc=array(0,64,128));

    // set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

    // set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

    //set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

    //set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

    //set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

    //set some language-dependent strings
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    // set default font subsetting mode
    $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

    // Set font
    // dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
    // print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
    // helvetica or times to reduce file size.
    $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);

    // remove default header
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);

    // Add a page
    // This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
    $pdf->AddPage();
```

//The queries and the printing to pdf

```
    //queries
    $c_name=DB::queryOneField('report_name',"SELECT * from reports r INNER JOIN report_fields rf on r.report_id=rf.report_id INNER JOIN searchcolumn s on rf.field_id=s.scol_id where r.report_id=%i",$_GET['c_id']);


    if($_GET['custom']==true)
    {
        $a=DB::query("SELECT * from reports r INNER JOIN report_fields rf on r.report_id=rf.report_id INNER JOIN searchcolumn s on rf.field_id=s.scol_id where r.report_id=%i",$_GET['c_id']);  
        $s = DB::query("SELECT * FROM alumni order by ln,batch ASC); //<-- ------------------ this is the part where it works if you add LIMIT 5 in the sql statement

        foreach($s as $m){
            foreach($a as $c){
        $line2 .=

        str_replace(",","",$c['advsearch_name']) . ": " . str_replace(",","",$m[$c['advsearch_col']]) . "<br />";

            }
        $line2 .="<br />";
        }

        $data="$line2";


    }


    // Set some content to print
    $html = <<<EOD
    <hr>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td width="60%">REPORTS - $rp_name</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    $data
    EOD;

    // Print text using writeHTMLCell()
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell($w=0, $h=0, $x='', $y='', $html, $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);
    ob_end_clean();

        // Close and output PDF document
        // This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
        $pdf->Output('application.pdf', 'I');
```

am i missing something?

thanks

Comment: Maybe there is problem if content cant fit on one page ?

Comment: How much data do you have? Also - add this code at the beginning of your code: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');` and see if you will get some errors (note that because of `ob_*` functions errors may be not seen - try remove them while testing)

Comment: theres a "TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file" warning that appears
also another thing i noticed about my output is that(this is with ob headers) once the data that needs to get printed goes past the fifth page the pdf no longer shows anything

Comment: That first error is self explaining. ob_end_clean is a thing that should fix it (but as for me, that is wrong approach. You should better figure out what is sent before your file and remove that code).

Comment: About fifth page: try to replace writeHTMLCell with simply writeHTML. (just a guess, I never tried to put long HTML with TCPDF). Also, TCPDF can take a lot of memory. I would try to set something like this: `set_time_limit(0);ini_set("memory_limit", "256M");` There just may be not enough memory to make a file.

Comment: do i place it at the beginning of the code? i tried but it still didnt work

Comment: I am working on a project which is similar with yours. I should print out about 750 labels by one query. Each label needs ~1MB hardware resource on the server therefore php memory_limit should be HIGH! For instance, my setting is 4G for memory_limit.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code at the beginning of the **TCPDF** script :

```
ob_start();
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit", "256M");
```